# Android ListView Card Design

Tags: android, listview

SO i am having a listView filled by data from an SQLite database. Now i want the items in that listView to look like Cards with shadows(like the popular Google now design for example). I tried many Solutions i found here on stackoverflow and else in the web, but None worked. So can someone maybe share a clear solution where to implement what to get that view correct?

this is the XML file where my listview is located

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.ein_siedler.putzplaner.activities.Main">



<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/button_activity_neueaufgabe"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
    android:onClick="öffnen_activity_NeueAufgabe"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    tools:ignore="RtlCompat,VectorDrawableCompat"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/button_activity_profil"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:onClick="öffnen_activity_Profil"
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_24dp"
    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/button_activity_gruppe"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:onClick="öffnen_activity_Gruppe"
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_group_white_24dp"
    tools:ignore="RtlCompat,VectorDrawableCompat"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        style="@style/ListView"
        android:id="@+id/listView_aufgaben"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

you can see some Trials here but None really worked, so pls help me get it:)
PS:ask if you Need any more Code snippets

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 ... item data 
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: the Problem is that i got a listview and changing it into a cardview would make many Problems, am i right?

Comment: Implement the cardView as parent of your itemAdapter not parent of listView

Comment: i dont have an itemAdapter, i jsut directly fill the listview from an arrayAdapter out of the db

Comment: Try to create a custom adapter :)
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html